# Valor entre formulários Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, get

Boa Tarde Pessoal
Estou pegando o valor de uma gridview até ai tudo bem:

```
gridCadastro.GetRowValues(gridCadastro.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'id_cliente', OnGetRowValues);
```

Agora preciso pegar esse valor e passar para um ASPxButton de uma metro.master, porém não consegui via

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>
```

Comment: você quer passa para outro form?

Comment: Por favor, explica melhor isso.

Comment: Bom vamos la.. Tenho uma aplicação onde um arquivo metro.master recebe os botões padrões.
E em outro lado tenho um formulário com uma gridview.
A ideia é quando o usuário clicar na gridview, o id da row seja passado para metro.master como parâmetro para eventuais funções.

Answer (score 0):

Na sua `Masterpage`, coloque um campo `Hiddenfield` com id que desejar.

A partir da sua tela, pra use:

```
(Masterpage.findcontrol("Id_do_hiddenfield_da_master_page") as HiddenField).value = "VALOR";
```

Comment: Tentei como informado e retornou o seguinte erro:
        
        Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: HiddenField

Comment: poderia me explicar melhor sua ideia....sou novo no asp.net c#, e não intendi